# How do I make one UIView to partially push down another on the tap of a title image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How do I achieve the following.

Customer taps title logo (the "a"):

[image]

Existing view is pushed down by new view:

[image]

Then to undo this the customer just taps the title logo again.

Comment: Do you use AutoLayout? If so, you can just do a block animation of the vertical constraint. Otherwise you would animate a new frame positions. And the animation is kicked in the gesture recognizer target action method.

Comment: I use AutoLayout yes. Is there a name for this procedure? I'd like to find some examples.

Comment: See sample in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of constraint animation with iOS 7 new springWithDamping. You need to make an `IBOutlet` from your top view top constraint that will push the other view down. Obviously you will do a reverse animation on the second tap.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0.1 usingSpringWithDamping:0.6 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{

    self.containerTop.constant = 60.0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // do stuff when animation finished
}];
```

Comment: When you say top view are you referring to the view that is already on screen? In this instance I have a collectionView on screen that is already an IBOutlet. So I'd just create the second view programmatically?

Comment: It depends on how you create the sliding top view (in storyboard or in code) and how are your constraints setup. If you have everything in storyboard, you can just create an outlet from one constraint that will drive all 3 views down. If you create the black view in code, then you need to include its frame or its constraints into the animation block. Imagine you have 2 view state positions, the starting state and the final state. If you can jump between these 2 states in code, then the animation block will just add the element of smooth animation with some fancy bouncing if you wish.

Comment: Spent some time reading up. I watched the apple developers custom transitions video and also this one [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncDxpQysZps) . Is the code you provided what I need to do what I want to do? or is there more to it? On the youTube video it shows how to animate one view. I was thinking maybe I can modify what is shown in the video but to work with two views. I understand both views are in a container. What if I change the frame of both views? Would this be enough and automatically move my navigation bar too?

Comment: Yes, you can put any number of views into the block to animate them.